# filedialog, python, save as

Tags: python, tkinter, savefiledialog, filedialog

i create a very simple photo editor. I've alredy create open-file and save-file button, and command to open file:

```
def Open(self):
        #Open Callback
        ftypes = [('Image Files', '*.tif *.jpg *.png')]
        dlg = filedialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
        filename = dlg.show()
        self.fn = filename
        self.setImage()
```

Now I want to create save command and I'm stuck:

```
 def save(self):
        myFormats = [('Windows Bitmap','*.bmp'),\
                     ('Portable Network Graphics','*.png'),\
                     ('JPEG / JFIF','*.jpg'),('CompuServer GIF','*.gif'),]
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
```

How to use this formats as formats my saving image?

Comment: Use this `filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=myFormats)`

Comment: @Zetys you should make an answer so this won't be listed under unanswered tab.

Comment: @Lafexlos thanks.i'll do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include those formats use `filetypes` option:

```
filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=myFormats)

if filename:
    #do save
```

For example if I open an image like this:

```
import Image
image = Image.open(filename)
```

To save I have just to do:

```
image.save(filename)
```

Comment: I sitll have one problem, when I want to save pic I press 'Save' but my image didn't saved. Where is a problem?

Comment: When you press `Save` it will return a file name, then you shoud use it to write image data.Check my edit.

Comment: @kasia Check my edit.I need to know how images are used to be able to do some thing.